# interwoven zorder for lines on two (twin) axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, multiple-axes

I'm plotting a series of lines on a pair of twin (`twinx`) axes.  I can control which lines are 'on top' of each axis using the `zorder` parameter, and I can set which axis (as a whole) is on top using the `Axes.set_zorder()` function --- making all of the lines on one axis above/below all of the lines on the other axis.  **Is there a way to interweave the lines between the two axes?**

For example, I want the upper plot (which uses a twin axis) to have the lines stacked in the same was as in the lower plot (which doesn't use a twin axis):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NUM_PNTS = 100
NUM_LINES = 10
scale = np.linspace(1.0,100.0,num=NUM)[::-1]

lines_left  = [ np.random.uniform(low=-scale, high=scale, size=NUM) 
                for ii in xrange(NUM_LINES) ]
lines_right = [ 50.0 + np.random.uniform(low=-scale, high=scale, size=NUM) 
                for ii in xrange(NUM_LINES) ]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[12,12], nrows=2)
tw = ax[0].twinx()

for ll,lr in zip(lines_left,lines_right):
    ax[0].plot(ll, c='b', lw=2.0)
    tw.plot(lr, c='r', lw=2.0)

    ax[1].plot(ll, c='b', lw=2.0)
    ax[1].plot(lr, c='r', lw=2.0)

tw.set_ylim(-150,150)
for axis in ax: axis.set_ylim(-150,150)
```

[image]

I've tried setting the zorder to be interspaced, but on different axes it doesn't work, i.e.

```
for ii,(ll,lr) in enumerate(lines_left, lines_right):
    ax[0].plot(ll, c='b', lw=2.0, zorder=2*ii  )
    tw.plot(lr,    c='b', lw=2.0, zorder=2*ii+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Axes have their own zorder as artists. From the `axes` documentation:

> set_zorder(level) Set the zorder for the artist. Artists with lower
>   zorder values are drawn first.
>
> ACCEPTS: any number

It seems reasonable that zorder of children within an axes, e.g. lines, is subordinate to zorder between multiple axes. And I think your code is a demonstration that this is so.

Given your goal, you might have to renorm the y-values for the second set of data (e.g., red, here), plot them interleaved, and then add a floating spine with tick *labels* that describe the un-renormed y-values for the red data.

Comment: Thanks, That's the same workaround I had in mind.  Maybe I'll put in a feature request to matplotlib